# Invalid identifier in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I haven't created any `columns(PAYMENTTERM)` in tables with double quotes but
still I'm getting following Error:

```
Error(26,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(27,29): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "P"."PAYMENTTERM": invalid identifier
```

Please point out what wrong am i doing and what needs to be corrected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PAYTERMUPDATE
IS
    RecordCount INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        count(1) INTO RecordCount 
    FROM 
        docmeta d 
    INNER JOIN temp_pay_term p ON d.XPROJECT_ID = p.PID
    WHERE
        lower(d.PAYMENTTERM) <> lower(p.PAYMENTTERM);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There were '
            || to_char(RecordCount)
            || ' records where payment term is mismatch.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');

    FOR X IN (
        SELECT p.PID, p.PAYMENTTERM
        FROM docmeta d, temp_pay_term p
        WHERE d.XPROJECT_ID = p.PID AND d.PAYMENTTERM <> p.PAYMENTTERM)
    LOOP
       UPDATE docmeta
           SET d.PAYMENTTERM = p.PAYMENTTERM
       WHERE XPROJECT_ID = X.PID;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-1000,
                    'Error occured, No payment term were updated');

END PAYTERMUPDATE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
UPDATE docmeta
SET d.PAYMENTTERM = p.PAYMENTTERM
WHERE XPROJECT_ID = X.PID ;
```

You must add an alias on docmeta (d) and the p.PAYMENTTERM alias must be X

So, change in this way your query:

```
UPDATE docmeta d
SET d.PAYMENTTERM = X.PAYMENTTERM
WHERE XPROJECT_ID = X.PID ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use loop variable as alias to `PAYMENTTERM` that is `X` in you case, also declare alias for `DOCMETA` as `d`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this?

```
LOOP 
    UPDATE docmeta d
    SET d.PAYMENTTERM = p.PAYMENTTERM
    WHERE XPROJECT_ID = X.PID ; 
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: `p.PAYMENTTERM` will still be invalid identifier.